# How to add items to a generic List in C#

Tags: c#, generics

When I was trying to add items to the generic list, I am unable to add, code I am using has been provided above, could any one suggest on this.

```
   Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle(2, false, "car", 50);
   Vehicle v3 = new Vehicle(3, false, "suv", 100);
   Vehicle v4 = new Vehicle(4, false, "suv", 100);

    public List<T> Initialize<T>() where T : Vehicle, new()
    {
        List <T> veh_list= new List<T>();

        //veh_list.Add(new T(1, false, "car", 50));

        veh_list.Add(v2);

        veh_list.Add(v3);
        veh_list.Add(v4);

        return veh_list;
   }
```

Error : Cannot Convert from Vehicle to T.

Comment: Why the `new()` constraint if the method doesn't create any `T`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want the method to return a generic list? Because it would be much easier to change the method signature to `public List<Vehicle> Initialize()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method shouldn't be generic in the first place.
Making the method generic would let callers write `Initialize<Truck>()`, and a `List<Truck>` cannot contain `Vehicle`s.

You should make a normal non-generic method that returns a `List<Vehicle>`.